# stringr str_extract capture group capturing everything

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm looking to extract the year from a string.  This always comes after an 'X' and before "." then a string of other characters.

Using `stringr`'s `str_extract` I'm trying the following:

```
year = str_extract(string = 'X2015.XML.Outgoing.pounds..millions.'
                 , pattern = 'X(\\d{4})\\.')
```

I thought the brackets would define the capture group, returning `2015`, but I actually get the complete match `X2015.`

Am I doing this correctly?  Why am i not trimming "X" and "."?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The capture group is irrelevant in this case. The function `str_extract` will return the whole match including characters before and after the capture group.

You have to work with lookbehind and lookahead instead. Their length is zero.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = 'X2015.XML.Outgoing.pounds..millions.',
            pattern = '(?<=X)\\d{4}(?=\\.)')
# [1] "2015"
```

This regex matches four consecutive digits that are preceded by an `X` and followed by a `.`.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the most idiomatic way is to use `str_match`:

```
str_match(string = 'X2015.XML.Outgoing.pounds..millions.',
          pattern = 'X(\\d{4})\\.')
```

Which returns the complete match followed by capture groups:

```
     [,1]     [,2]  
[1,] "X2015." "2015"
```

As such the following will do the trick:

```
str_match(string = 'X2015.XML.Outgoing.pounds..millions.',
          pattern = 'X(\\d{4})\\.')[2]
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can use `gsub`:

```
string = 'X2015.XML.Outgoing.pounds..millions.'

gsub("X(\\d{4})\\..*", "\\1", string)
# [1] "2015"
```

or `str_replace` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(string, "X(\\d{4})\\..*", "\\1")
# [1] "2015"
```