# Extracting specific parts of an input string using stringr package in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Basically, this is my input;

```
"a ~ b c d*e !r x"
"a ~ b c"
"a ~ b c d1 !r y",
"a ~ b c D !r z",
"a~b c d*e!r z"
```

and would desire this as my result;

```
"b c d*e"
"b c"
"b c d1"
"b c D"
"b c d*e"
```

The input represents (mixed) models that are built up of three groups, i.e. the dependent part (`~`) the fixed part and the random part (`!r`). I thought with capture groups it would be easy enough ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787725/stringr-str-extract-capture-group-capturing-everything)). The difficulty is the random part which is not always present.

I tried different things as you can see below and of course it possible to do this in two steps. However, I desire a (robust) regex one-liner - I feel that should be possible. I employed these different sources as well for inspiration; [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do), [string replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/replace-specific-characters-within-strings) and [string removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/remove-part-of-a-string).

```r
library(stringr)
txt <- c("a ~ b c d*e !r x",
         "a ~ b c",
         "a ~ b c d1 !r y",
         "a ~ b c D !r z",
         "a~b c d*e!r z")

# Different tries with capture groups
str_replace(txt, "^.*~ (.*) !r.*$", "\\1")
> [1] "b c d*e"       "a ~ b c"       "b c d1"        "b c D"        
> [5] "a~b c d*e!r z"
str_replace(txt, "^(.*~ )(.*)( !r.*)$", "\\2")
> [1] "b c d*e"       "a ~ b c"       "b c d1"        "b c D"        
> [5] "a~b c d*e!r z"
str_replace(txt, "^(.*~)(.*)(!r.*|\n)$", "\\1\\2")
> [1] "a ~ b c d*e " "a ~ b c"      "a ~ b c d1 "  "a ~ b c D "  
> [5] "a~b c d*e"
str_replace(txt, "^(.*) ~ (.*)!r.*($)", "\\2")
> [1] "b c d*e "      "a ~ b c"       "b c d1 "       "b c D "       
> [5] "a~b c d*e!r z"
str_replace(txt, "^.* ~ (.*)(!r.*|\n)$", "\\1")
> [1] "b c d*e "      "a ~ b c"       "b c d1 "       "b c D "       
> [5] "a~b c d*e!r z"


# Multiple steps
step1 <- str_replace(txt, "^.*~\\s*", "")
step2 <- str_replace(step1, "\\s*!r.*$", "")
step2
> "b c d*e" "b c"     "b c d1"  "b c D"   "b c d*e"
```

**EDIT:** After posting I kept playing around and found something that worked for my particular case.

```r
# My (probably non-robust) solution/monstrosity
str_replace(txt, "(^.*~\\s*(.*)\\s*!r.*$|^.*~\\s*(.*)$)", "\\2\\3")
> "b c d*e " "b c"      "b c d1 "  "b c D "   "b c d*e"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest removing all from the start and up to and incluiding the first tilde (with optional whitespaces) and all starting with the first `!r` as whole word:

```
gsub("^[^~]+~\\s*|\\s*!r\\b.*", "", txt)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r16YyL/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^~]+` - 1+ chars other than `~`
- `~` - a `~` char
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `!r` - `!r` substring
- `\\b` - word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/4BfQem):

```
txt <- c("a ~ b c d*e !r x",
         "a ~ b c",
         "a ~ b c d1 !r y",
         "a ~ b c D !r z",
         "a~b c d*e!r z")
gsub("^[^~]+~\\s*|\\s*!r\\b.*", "", txt)
## => [1] "b c d*e" "b c"     "b c d1"  "b c D"   "b c d*e"
```

Comment: I ended up using this for my final solution. Hence, this was chosen as answer.

Answer (score 3):

What about str_extract() using *positive lookbehind* and *lookahead*?

```
str_extract(st, "(?<=~)[^!]+") %>% trimws()
[1] "b c d*e" "b c"     "b c d1"  "b c D"   "b c d*e"
```

My try to rephrase in English:

> We are looking for something that is preceded by a ~ `(?<=~)`, and is a sequence of 1 or more characters that are not ! `[^!]+`, when we have found something that fits our criteria we stop searching that string (otherwise use `str_extract_all()`). Finalement, if what we extracted has any spaces at the start of end of string, then remove them `trimws()`.

**Data:**

```
st <- c(
  'a ~ b c d*e !r x',
  'a ~ b c',
  'a ~ b c d1 !r y',
  'a ~ b c D !r z',
  'a~b c d*e!r z'
)
```

**EDIT**

Few updates already as examples of inputs grow. Will not update again.

Comment: Interesting, will play around with this. After posting I came up with my own regex monstrosity that seems to work (also works on more cases); `str_replace(st, "(^.*~\\s*(.*)\\s*!r.*$|^.*~\\s*(.*)$)", "\\2\\3")`. It's a shame that with the first string there is  an extra space at the end. Nothing `str_trim` can't handle, but still...

Comment: you mind if I throw some more cases at your solution that might "break" it?

Comment: Sure throw them in - but better that you asked.

Comment: My question is oversimplification of the my actual problem. For example, I used `a` and `b` but in actual fact this can also be `b1` or `X`. So additional cases like `st <- c(st, "a ~ b c d1 !r y", "a ~ b c D ! r z")` won't get desired result. **EDIT**: `str_extract(txt, "(?<=~\\s)[a-zA-Z0-9*\\s]+(?=\\b)")` improves it already...

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand these positive/negative look ahead/behinds ..not very intuitive .. for me at least ..for now..

Comment: @tstev Made another one and a final update. The current one only has a lookbehind which is `(?<=~)` and means *has to be preceded by `~`*.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will let you extract with first capturing group the text you want: `~ ?([\w\*\-\+\/ ]+)(!r)?`.

First capturing group: `[\w\*\-\+\/ ]+` matches any word character `\w` or `*`, `+`, `-`, `\` and space  one or more times (`+`). It will be terminetaed before second capturing group (if any) `(!r)?`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Py8IHO/4)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! However I can't seem to get this to work in `R` with the `stringr` package. i.e. it didn't remove the characters before the `~` or after the `!r` so I edited to: `str_replace(txt, ".*~ ?([\\w\\*\\-\\+\\/ ]*)(!r.*)?", "\\1")` and this seems to work for my cases. Perhaps you meant to use in a different way?