# How to extract everything after a specific string?

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to extract everything after "-" in vector of strings in R.

For example in :

```
test = c("Pierre-Pomme","Jean-Poire","Michel-Fraise")
```

I'd like to get

```
c("Pomme","Poire","Fraise")
```

Thanks !

Comment: See also: [Extract a substring according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `str_extract`. `\\b` is a zero-length token that matches a word-boundary. This includes any non-word characters:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, '\\b\\w+$')
# [1] "Pomme"  "Poire"  "Fraise"
```

We can also use a back reference with `sub`. `\\1` refers to string matched by the first capture group `(.+)`, which is any character one or more times following a `-` at the end:

```
sub('.+-(.+)', '\\1', test)
# [1] "Pomme"  "Poire"  "Fraise"
```

This also works with `str_replace` if that is already loaded:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(test, '.+-(.+)', '\\1')
# [1] "Pomme"  "Poire"  "Fraise"
```

Third option would be using `strsplit` and extract the second word from each element of the list (similar to `word` from @akrun's answer):

```
sapply(strsplit(test, '-'), `[`, 2)
# [1] "Pomme"  "Poire"  "Fraise"
```

`stringr` also has  `str_split` variant to this:

```
str_split(test, '-', simplify = TRUE)[,2]
# [1] "Pomme"  "Poire"  "Fraise"
```

Answer (score 17):

We can use `sub` to match characters (`.*`) until the `-` and in the replacement specify `""`

```
sub(".*-", "", test)
```

---

Or another option is `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(test, 2, sep="-")
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answers might be what you're looking for, but if you don't want to lose the original context you can try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(test) %>% 
    separate(test, c("first", "last"), remove = F)
```

This will return a dataframe containing the original strings plus components, which might be more useful down the road:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  test          first  last  
  <chr>         <chr>  <chr> 
1 Pierre-Pomme  Pierre Pomme 
2 Jean-Poire    Jean   Poire 
3 Michel-Fraise Michel Fraise
```

Comment: How do you specify where to separate the text if there were more than one "-" in the test column?

Comment: @ORStudent you can try using more complex regex in the `sep` argument. You can also use integers to specify exact positions, which means you can use something like `str_locate_all` to find all occurrences of a separator and then specify which one, exactly, should be separated on.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the responses here didn't work for my particular string. I found this response more helpful (i.e., using Stringr's *lookbehind* function): [stringr str_extract capture group capturing everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787725/stringr-str-extract-capture-group-capturing-everything).

Comment: This answer could be more helpful if you could kindly provide a short summary of your reference and a simple showcase.